# What is "corporate drag"?

Tags: financial-literacy, stock-valuation

What is meant by the term *corporate drag*? Have seen this in some valuation analyses associated with a numerical cost value, but googling terms like "corporate drag" or "corporate drag value" do not appear to yield any results on the term.

Comment: I think that is what the rank and file employees feel on a day-to-day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer appears to be be found here (https://books.google.com/books?id=-YZXDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT929&ots=fB1RBC42rt&dq=%22corporate%20drag%22%20costs&pg=PT922#v=onepage&q=%22corporate%20drag%22%20costs&f=false) in a snippet of a book by Professor Aswath Damodaran covering the valuation of user-based companies:

> *corporate drag* -- those expenses that are indespensible to business
>   existence but are unrelated to users - and netting that value out of
>   the user value
>
> value of a user-based company = (value of existing users) + (value of
>   new users) - (value of corporate drag)

If there is a more general description of drag or corporate drag that I am missing here, anyone please let me know.